# Создание расписания php

Tags: php

Столкнулся с трудностями в создании скрипта, который будет создавать расписание для игр футбольного турнира.

> Дано:
>
> N-количество команд
>
> Каждая команда играет с каждой (круговая система)
>
> Количество туров: N-1 (команда не может играть сама с собой)
>
> Команда не может играть 2 раза за 1 тур; команда может играть с другой командой лишь 1 раз за время турнира

На данный момент продумываю идеологию этого скрипта. Сейчас считаю нормальным сделать вот так:

```
$count_teams = количество команд в турнире
$array_games = массив, в который будем записывать все игры
for ($i, $i < $count_teams; $i++) {
     *составить пары из массива $count_teams* (Как это сделать???) 
     *проверить, не играла ли данная пара в турнире*
     *если не играла, записать в массив игру*  
}
```

На выходе хочу получить такой массив:

```
$arr = array(
   'tour1' => array(
      '0' => array (
         '0' => 'team1',
         '1' => 'team2'
      )
      '1' => array (
         '0' => 'team3',
         '1' => 'team4'
      )
   )
'tour2' => array(
      '0' => array (
         '0' => 'team1',
         '1' => 'team4'
      )
      '1' => array (
         '0' => 'team2',
         '1' => 'team3'
      )
   )
);
```

Остался лишь вопрос в реализации этого. Как считаете, насколько это правильно? Какие есть еще методы создания данного функционала? Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Нашел точный аналог того, что мне нужно - http://challonge.com/ru/tournament/bracket_generator
Вопрос 1 - как сделать это на php?

Comment: И как ты будешь этот массив хранить?

Comment: @Alex78191 циклом буду записывать игры в БД

Comment: Сразу в бд записывай

Comment: @Alex78191 учитывая, что игр будет много, хочу все делать одним запросом. Поэтому делаю массив, потом в скрипте записи в бд формирую запрос - INSERT INTO games (params) VALUES *сюда идет запись строки из цикла*

Comment: Чем это отличается от того, чтобы сразу в бд вставлять? `INSERT INTO games (params) VALUES сюда идет запись строки из цикла`

Comment: @Alex78191 тем, что если в цикле вставлять каждый раз игру в БД, то количество запросов будет равно количеству игр, а это не есть хорошо. При цикле и последующем выводе в скрипт отправки в БД, создается 1 большой запрос - экономия ресурсов, все дела

Comment: Тут вопрос не в записи данных, а в генерации сетки

Comment: @Alexxosipov `циклом буду записывать игры в БД`, `учитывая, что игр будет много, хочу все делать одним запросом` <-- вы не находите это противоречивым?

Comment: @Alexxosipov не занимайтесь ерундой. Ну сколько у вас там будет игр? Тысяча, десять тысяч запросов - это для любой БД на самом непритязательном железе - тьфу и растереть. Переусложняя код и расставляя подобные костыли вы рискуете нарваться на гораздо более неприятные проблемы.

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо за совет!) Самое интересное, что вопрос был совсем не об этом))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function teamInTour($tour, $team){
    foreach($tour as $game){
        if(in_array($team, $game))return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$teams=['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12'];
$tours=[];
$games=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($teams);$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($teams);$j++){
        $games[]=[$teams[$i],$teams[$j]];
    }
}
echo "games:".count($games)." by tour:".(count($games)/(count($teams)-1));
$saved=$games;
for($i=0;$i<count($teams)-1;$i++){
    $name='tour'.$i;
    $tours[$name]=[];
    $games=$saved;
    foreach($games as $key=>$game){
        if(teamInTour($tours[$name],$game[0])||teamInTour($tours[$name],$game[1])){
            $saved[]=$game;
            continue;
        }
        $tours[$name][]=$game;
    }
}

print_r($tours);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31f0adedf5bab8f5fd3c4b5a0545329bfcf484f2)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Есть только 1 вопрос: каким образом можно перемешать игры в каждом туре?
Сделал `foreach($tours as $t) {shuffle($t);}` но в результате ничего не происходит

Comment: @Alexxosipov добавил в ответ. Ваш вариант рабочий, только элементы надо по ссылке перебирать

Comment: @rjhdnby сейчас доделываю скрипт, нашел один баг - если добавить не 8, а 10 команд, получается полная лажа http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb53a01e3da37d18ecbf0a443b2bafa99098b523
Не понимаю, в чем дело :(

Comment: сделал вывод количества игр в массиве в конце for, получается, что после первой игры из массива с играми убирается по 5 команд, далее по 4, а в конце - по 2. Не понимаю, почему

Comment: если перемешиваю массив $games после его создания (shuffle($games);), то результат иногда меняется, но смысл остается - некоторые игры почему-то просто не вставляются в массив $tours и остаются в $games

Comment: массив содержит $games содержит только 9 и 10 команду, которую я добавил.

Comment: скрипт работает только при 4, 8, 16, 32 и т.д. командах, иначе нет

Comment: @Alexxosipov поправил, теперь, вроде, для любого четного количества работает (для нечетного в принципе такая схема игр работать не будет)